# Is there and what is the official name for omitting words from phrases?

Tags: informal-language

When somebody says "Be all right" with the implied meaning of "It will be all right" or, similarly, saying "Hope for us yet" with the implied meaning of "There is hope for us yet" how would you call such a phenomenon of omitting words and is there even a name for it in the linguistic circles?

Comment: What research have you done?

Comment: There is a phenomenon called *diary drop* in which subject pronouns are omitted: https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/80730/is-there-a-name-for-the-practice-of-dropping-pronouns-in-written-speech

Comment: @stangdon diary drop is also a form of ellipsis?

Comment: @MichaelMunta  I think you could call it a form of ellipsis, yes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Elliptical construction.** This is a figure of speech where words are deliberately left out in a sentence but the meaning remains clear, it's often used in informal writing or speech to make it more concise and to the point.

> Full: I ate steak, and Jennifer ate fish.

> Elliptical: I ate steak, and Jennifer, [ate] fish.

Source of quotes: [GrammarBook.com](https://www.grammarbook.com/blog/clauses-sentences/elliptical-sentence-constructions/)

Comment: When quoting other sources, you must cite them. Not citing them is plagiarism which is not accepted on this site. We have added a source to this one for you.